# Why it is giving NoSuchMethodFound Error while showing the string is passed in tried calling?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am accessing address from Google map api and unable to get it added in a list. When printed it , it is printing the output but not adding it to the list address1 List.
I have tried it several times but it is not working.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:ambulance_service/models/placeDetails.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

const kGoogleApiKey = "MyGoogleMapKey";
List address1;
Future<List> getPlaces(double lat, double long) async {
String apiUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=$lat,$long&radius=1500&type=hospital&keyword=hospital&key=$kGoogleApiKey";
http.Response response = await http.get(apiUrl);
var places = <PlaceDetail1>[];
List data = json.decode(response.body)['results'];
int i = 0;
await wow(data);
data.forEach((f) =>
   places.add(new PlaceDetail(
      f['icon'], f['rating'].toString(), f['name'], f['place_id'])));

return places;
}

 Future<String> getPlaceAddress(String placeId) async {
  String apiUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?                
placeid=$placeId&key=$kGoogleApiKey";
http.Response response = await http.get(apiUrl);
Map<dynamic,dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body)['result'];
return data['formatted_address'].toString();
 }

Future<String> getPlaceMob(String placeId) async {
String apiUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json? 
 placeid=$placeId&key=$kGoogleApiKey";
http.Response response = await http.get(apiUrl);
Map<dynamic,dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body)['result'];
return data['formatted_address'].toString();
}

wow(List a)async{
for(var data in a){
String a =await getPlaceAddress(data['place_id']);
print(a);
address1.add(a);
 }
}




                          PLaceDetail is like:






 class PlaceDetail1{
 String icon,name,place_id,rating;

   PlaceDetail1(this.icon,this.rating,this.name,this.place_id);

 }

class PlaceDetail extends PlaceDetail1{
 String formatted_address,formatted_phone_number;

  PlaceDetail(String icon,String name,String place_id,String rating,[this.formatted_address,this.formatted_phone_number]):super(icon,name,place_id,rating);

 }



                           Errors:


I/flutter (18570): 01, Zoo Rd, Azad Nagar, Nawabganj, Kanpur, Uttar Pradesh 208002, India
E/flutter (18570): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (18570): NoSuchMethodError: The method 'add' was called on null.
E/flutter (18570): Receiver: null
E/flutter (18570): Tried calling: add("01, Zoo Rd, Azad Nagar, Nawabganj, Kanpur, Uttar Pradesh 208002, India")
E/flutter (18570): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:50:5)
E/flutter (18570): #1      wow (package:ambulance_service/data_from_api/google_maps_api_data.dart:48:14)
E/flutter (18570): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18570): #2      getPlaces (package:ambulance_service/data_from_api/google_maps_api_data.dart:19:9)
E/flutter (18570): <asynchronous suspension>
```

In above Errors:
It is saying The method 'add' was called on null and showing that it tried
Tried calling: add("01, Zoo Rd, Azad Nagar, Nawabganj, Kanpur, Uttar Pradesh 208002, India")
this shows a string is tried to pass in add but it is showing null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `List address1;` which is never initialized to a list value, so it has the value `null`. In the error message "The method 'add' was called on null", the "called *on*" means the left side - so `address1` is null.

Try `var address1 = <String>[];` (or `final address1 = <String>[]`) to initialize with an empty list so the `.add()` call can succeed.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you've not initialized your `List`, thus, it's a `null` pointer and you're trying to call `add` on it.

Just replace your `List address1;` with `final List<String> address1 = List<String>();`